# Selecting non duplicates from distint query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, duplicates

I am fighting with an SQL query and I am not able to solve it. A have a table like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Field1, Field2 
FROM myTable 
WHERE Field3 = 'value';
```

```
ID  Field1  Field2
1   Yes     Info
1   No      Info
2   Yes     Info
3   No      Info
3   Yes     Info
4   No      Info
```

I would like to have a resulting query where I don't have any duplicate values. In case of having duplicates values I would like to have a resulting 'Yes' and in other case I would like to have the existing value in that Field (Yes or No).

```
ID  Field1  Field2
1   Yes     Info
2   Yes     Info
3   Yes     Info
4   No      Info
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using an SQL Server. All the answers worked, I used the MAX answer because it took the smallest time to complete. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to preferentially choose `Yes` over `No` for a given pair of records corresponding to an ID, then you can choose the max of `Field1` (and the max of `Field2`):

```
SELECT ID, MAX(Field1) AS Field1, MAX(Field2) AS Field2
FROM myTable
WHERE Field3 = 'value'
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Good one, as far I have seen `mysql` automatically taken the first row (or values of first row) when you perform grouping on rows

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo Yes, it does this...but only in certain versions.  In the latest version of MySQL your query might not run, hence you might want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Group it by `id`, it will automatically do the job

```
 SELECT DISTINCT Field1, Field2 FROM myTable WHERE Field3 = 'value' group by id
```

Comment: This won't work (I think) because you are selecting columns which do not appear in `GROUP BY` (and also are not aggregates).

Comment: it works in mysql and yes it doesn't in postgres @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GROUP BY query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(* ) > 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE Field1 END AS Field1, Field2 FROM myTable GROUP BY 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select DISTINCT 
ID,
case
 when (group_concat(Field1))="YesNo" then "Yes"
 when (group_concat(Field1))="NoYes" then "Yes"
 else (group_concat(Field1)) 
end as Field1,
Field2 from
(SELECT DISTINCT ID,Field1, Field2 
FROM myTable 
WHERE Field3 = 'value')A
group by ID
```